# Ubuntu 18.04 installation not allowing choice of dual boot for Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

Laptop is ASUS model X53E. I have windows 7 64bit Home addition.  I want to setup Laptop as Dual boot.  I have compressed the Windows drive and now I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Desktop.  During installation of Ubuntu I get to the page asking me how I want to load set up Ubuntu.  I do NOT get an option to set up dual boot.  My choice is for complete Wipe of Windows 7.  NO option for dual boot. Do I need to attempt to load a different Release of Ubuntu and then upgrade to 18.03.3 LTS.
Thank you

Comment: Is Windows hibernated? Or drive(s) not in AHCI mode in BIOS/UEFI. Windows 7 was normally BIOS, your system looks like early UEFI. have you updated UEFI/BIOS? Waht video card/chip? Or did Windows convert to dynamic partitions or use all 4 primary partitions? Does live installer work ok in live mode? If so post this in question above: `sudo parted -l` and this: `sudo fdisk -lu` Similar output but some differences.

Comment: I boot UBuntu off of a USB.  I understand this to be Ubuntu live installer. 
 I have choice to install or use Ubuntu on USB.  Issue is with live installer. 
 Windows does not boot.  I have set unit to use BIOS,drives in AHCI mode.  The laptop came with 4 partitions.  After shrinking Windows I did end up with 6 partitions.  I now have gotten the laptop down to 4 useale partitions.  I have created a partion that is now correctly seen by Ubuntu.

Comment: I am getting the requested fdisk and parted files uploaded.  thanks for your help

Comment: If in Windows you created more than 4 MBR partitions, then it may have converted to dynamic (proprietary) partitioning. Newer Windows needs AHCI driver installed before changing to AHCI in UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: I was not able to find an update for AHCI driver on my windows/ASUS laptop.  I decided to work through the Ubuntu installation.  I picked Installation Type>Something Else.   I went ahead and put Ubuntu on the last partition on the Laptop Drive.  Followed through the install and LEFT the Ubuntu Flash drive in during reboot.  The install was flawless.  I now can choose between windows or Unbuntu load.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was going ahead with Installation type and choosing Something Else, loading Ubuntu on last partition of drive.  Able to boot Ubuntu and Windows 7.  Ubuntu can also access file system on the "windows" partition.  I also want to thank all those who gave me guidance on this issue. It has been a LONG time since I had to mess with volumes,partitions, Boot loader etc.  Again thanks for all the help.